# update data from server every 10 minits

Tags: android

I wrote an Android application which sends JSON requests to a server every 10 minutes to get passages and sometimes play an alarm. (depends on the server data). I tried different ways to realize this mechanism but nothing works 100% correctly.

Now I use AlarmManager which will start the service and that service will start asynkTask for a request to the server.
Sadly this doesn't work as it should. Sometimes the application calls but sometimes it doesn't. (I mean server data when it should be called) What did I do wrong?

I created a service in MainActivity:

```
private void createService() {
    this.intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Autobus66Service.class);
    Date dateTime = new Date();
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,dateTime.getHours());
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,dateTime.getMinutes());

    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this,0,intent,0);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            Convert.toMiliseconds(Preferences.ALARM_PERIOD),pIntent);
}
```

at the service:

```
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    createNotification();
    DisplayLoggingInfo();   
}



private void DisplayLoggingInfo() {
    if(MainActivity.isLoaderRunning==false){
        new LoaderInBackground(getApplicationContext(),
            Autobus66Service.this).execute((Void[]) null);
    }
    Preferences prefs = new Preferences(this);
    boolean doActivityLoading = prefs.doActivityLoading();
    if (doActivityLoading) {
        isRunning = MainActivity.isActive;
        closeAnotherActivities();
        Log.d("Autobus66Service isMainActivityRunning"+isRunning,MainActivity.TAG6);
        if (isRunning)   {
            MainActivity.isCallFromAnotherActivity = true;
            sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
       else {
            startActvityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(startActvityIntent);
        }
        Autobus66WakeLock.lockOn(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the best way is to do it is to use the Handler `postDelayed` method with a `Runnable` executing your `AsyncWorker`. When a `Runnable` executes it can reschedule itself, and you can cancel future executions that way also.

Examples (not tested):

```
 Handler handler = new Handler(); //or some other way of obtaining the
 handler handler.post( new Runnable {
 public void run()
 {
   yourAsyncTask.execute();
   handler.postDelayed(this,600000);
 }
});
```

When stopping, just call:

```
handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
```

Comment: I tried this approach, when phone will be in sleeping mode it won't work.

Comment: Then take a look at @Slv3r answer. You probably need to force the phone to stay awake. Just keep in mind that with certain brands wake locks do not prevent sensors from shutting down which can be a real problem. But from your code I think that does not effect you.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code stop working when device enter in deep sleep mode. To avoid this when your intent of AlarmManager is received by your class (Autobus66Service.class) you have to force the device to wake up by using `PowerManager.WakeLock` like this way:

```
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);           
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
    wl.acquire();
```

and when your task has finished call

```
    wl.release();
```

be sure to release wakelock as soon as possible to save battery life.

P.S. don't forget to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />` in your manifest.